# Clean Build Java Command Line

Tags: java, command-line, compilation

I am compiling my project written using eclipse using the command line as follows

`javac file.java`

And then to run:

`java file (args here)`

How would  I run a clean build, or compilation? Whenever I recompile, the changes are not getting affected unless I delete all the `.class` files and recompile. Please note that the the main file will call other classes too.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're compiling by hand at the command line if you've got your project in eclipse already??

Comment: Eclipse isn't taking the file name in the argument. It keeps saying file not found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should compile all the Java files in your application to be sure, basically.

Options include:

- Use a full build system such as Ant.
- On a Unix box, use something like:

  ```
  javac `find . -name '*.java'`
  ```

  assuming you don't have too many (or use `xargs` if necessary).
- If you're not using packages (and you really should be) you can just use:

  ```
  javac *.java
  ```

Comment: Oh yeah - that is the problem.. I am running Mac OS X. I used your code above and it didn't work. How do I compile all .java files in a directory?

Comment: Also, it is a good idea to write all your output to a target directory, using the `-d` command line option. Deleting old content is then as simple as deleting all content in the target directory.

Comment: If OP isn't using packages, and all the .java files are in the same directory, just use `javac *.java`. It's simpler, and it has the advantage of working on platforms that don't have back-tick substitution and/or the `find` command.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I handle this.

```
rm $(find . -name "*.class")
javac <MainClass>.java
java <MainClass>
```

It's a simple trick that removes all files ending with the extension ".class".
When you compile with `javac`, it will compile all the files again without you having to worry about directory structure either.

In case you are on windows you can get the alternative for find [here.](https://superuser.com/questions/401495/equivalent-of-unix-find-command-on-windows)