# Clean and build Netbeans java project from command line

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, command-line

I have a java application project (ant) under Netbeans and I want to programmatically call the action similar to Netbeans' clean and build (clean the project and than build it) command using something like javac or ant. How am I supposed to do that? I've already look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339886/clean-build-java-command-line) but it didn't help me.

Comment: What a clean build differ from a dirty build?

Comment: Sorry, there was an "and" missing, it's clean and build

Comment: Downvoter can please tell me the reason?

Comment: I'm currently in the home office, and running netbeans over an ssh tunnel is awfully slow. For that reason, an option to start netbeans with a command line parameter to automatically clean and build a given project would be very helpful. Writing the ant script myself, as proposed by Paulius, seems like busywork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans for clean and build is using [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) (If it is not a maven project). Make some research of it (try with [Writing a Simple Buildfile](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html)) and you will be able to do the same with your project by writing `Ant` build script for it.

Comment: I already have the build files, I want to run ant using those netbeans created build files

Comment: Well, netbeans is generating ant script automatically, so they are IDE dependent. I would not suggest try running or modifying those scripts. Also netbeans generates a lot of crap in those files, you should write them your self, then you'll know what you are doing exactly. To generate ANT scripts automatically is almost the same as to create a web page using FrontPage.

Comment: You must be right, I used netbeans' ant-launcher.jar to build my project and it gives error while parsing build files.